# Запустить команду при помощи скрипта в уже запущенной утилите силами shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Суть вопроса в следующем:

Есть последовательность действий в консоли: Поочерёдный запуск команд - Запуск отдельной утилиты - Поочерёдный запуск команд

Я хочу это всё автоматизировать, написав .sh-ник. Я упёрся в то, что запуск первых команд проходит успешно, потом запускается утилита (принимающая уже свои команды) и я совершенно не имею представления, как можно в эту утилиту засунуть команду силами /bin/sh. Есть у кого-нибудь идеи?

Выглядит всё примерно так:

```
command1
command2
command_for_utility_launch
utility_command1
utility_command2
utility_exit_command
command3
```

Comment: Выглядит как банальный пайп, нет?

Comment: Я уверен, что тут что-то банальное. Просто я не знаю, что)) Что такое "пайп"?

Comment: Пайп не нужен. Нужно использовать  "here document" на stdin команды ([см. тут](http://linux-training.be/funhtml/ch18.html#idp54195584))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если утилита умеет принимать пайп, то так

```
command1
command2

cat << EOF | command_for_utility_launch

utility_command1
utility_command2
utility_exit_command

EOF

command3
```

*П.С. через echo не удобно писать многострочные команды*

Comment: Тут даже `cat`  не нужен. Можно сразу `command_for_utility_launch << EOF .... EOF` Насколько помню по русски такая штука (перенаправление текста скрипта на stdin команды) называется "встроенный документ" (here document в оригинале)

Comment: Так теряется семантика выход -> вход. По мне с cat уютнее

Comment: "Be nice" -- говорю я себе

Comment: Заработало. Спасибо огромное. А вопрос со звёздочкой можно?)) В этой утилите мы загоняем первую команду и получаем некий айдишник (внутри этой утилиты). А можно ли этот айдишник загнать в переменную? Вариант ID=${command} не срабатывает.

Comment: Что за команды то? Пока не поятно

Comment: мы запускаем wpa_cli (вышеуказанная утилита). Там прописываем add_network (получаем айдишник сети). Следующие команды опираются на этот айдишник. Соответственно, мне нужно получить айдишник сети, засунуть его в переменную, потом юзать переменную в последующих командах внутри wpa_cli. После этого мы прописываем quit для выхода и продолжаем выполнение скрипта уже вне wpa_cli.

В обычном скрипте я бы просто прописал ID=${add_network}
Но внутри wpa_cli эта петрушка не работает.

Comment: То есть я использую ID=$(add_network). Обычные скобки, не фигурные.

Comment: С wpa я по dbus общаюсь) ну гляну вечером

Comment: @DamienDamieAmfiet у меня переменные работают, вот посмотри примеры тут  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17983608/2101808

Comment: и укруглые тоже.. надо смотреть глубже

Comment: @eri По примерам не совсем тот кейс. Привету кусок скрипта, чтобы понятно было, в чём затык:
#!/bin/sh
cat << EOF | wpa_cli #запуск впа_кли. Всё ниже будет выполняться уже в окружении впа
ID=$(add_network) #я прописываю команду для получения внутри впа айдишника сети и засовываю его в переменную ID. тут затык, потому что впа расцениваться всю строчку как команду. нужно именно через переменную, так как айдишник постоянно меняется
set_network $ID ssid "HomeWiFi" #я использую полученный айдишник сети для добавления сети, но, так как предыдущий шаг зафейлился, зафейлился и этот

Answer (score 1):

Многие интерпретаторы принимают команды из *stdin*, поэтому можно
использовать
[перенаправления](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)
(также «пайпы», от англ. «*pipes*»).  Вот пример с *psql*:

```sh
echo "one"
echo "two"
echo '
SELECT 3;
SELECT 4;
' | env PGPASSWORD="postgres" psql -U "postgres"
echo "five"
```

Answer (score 1):

На случай если команда не поддерживает прием из stdin на помощь придет expect

Не знаю как сейчас, но в старых дистрибутивах из коробки не шел, поэтому требуется установка для начала

```
...
expect -c 'spawn command_for_utility_launch
expect "Если есть текст приветствия ПО писать тут"
send -- "utility_command1\r"
send -- "utility_command2\r"
send -- "utility_exit_command\r"'
...
```

На хабре есть статься: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/328436/