# Выполнение команд в окне программы

Tags: linux, bash

Linux.
bash.
У меня имеется программа #1, при запуске которой открывается консоль самой программы #1. В программе #1 можно вводить свои команды, но основные команды терминала работать не будут. Также и наоборот.
Теперь я хочу сделать программу #2 на bash, которая могла бы выполнять команды в программе #1. Если я создаю простую программу #2 где она выполняет например команду help, то она выполняет ее в основном терминале, а не в программе #1. Дело в том, что у программы #1 нет открытого кода и мне нужно придумать обходной путь.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запустить команду при помощи скрипта в уже запущенной утилите силами shell](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1108441/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-shell)

Comment: ещё, возможно, подразумевалось что-то типа [xdotool](https://habr.com/ru/post/214779/)